# How to change the result when file does not exist in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a problem to print out the result when a file does not exist. Let's say I use this code in bash

```
v1=`cat /ieee80211/phy2/rcstats`
echo $v1
```

When the file exists, it will display the value like this

```
0.8
0.6
0.3
```

But when file doesn't exist, it will just display :

```
cat: /ieee80211/phy2/rcstats: No such file or directory
```

How to change that warning into `1.0` ?

What I know, I just do like this

```
if [! -f $v1]; then
  echo "1.0"
fi
```

but the result it will just print `1.0` when the file exists, and the warning still appears

What should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best error handling in this case is to check whether the file exist and if so, do the `cat`, not the other way round.

Like this:

```
file="/ieee80211/phy2/rcstats"
if [ -f $file ]
then
    v1=$(< $file)
fi
```

Comment: It's not exactly the best error handling: you'll have an error if file is not readable. Even, you might have an error if the `cat` fails in the middle of processing.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works with little modification, in my case
if [ -f $file ]
then
    v1='1.0'
else
    v1=`cat $file`
fi

Comment: It depends on how far you want to go with error handling, but you're right, there are more things to check if you want to be really safe.

Comment: bash has a shorthand for `$(cat $file)` --> `v=$(< $file)`. That will save you a couple of milliseconds

Comment: Nice, didn't know about it!

Answer (score 4):

`[` is a command. It needs spaces between it and its first argument.

```
if [ ! ... ]; then
    ^
   here
```

Comment: I've edited your answer for future readers. If you think change is irrelevant feel free to roll-back changes. :)

Comment: @PLB: S'okay, people get notifications when their (non-wiki) stuff is edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to handle the case where the file doesn't exist, you might as well just use:

```
{ v1=$( </ieee80211/phy2/rcstats ) ; } 2>/dev/null
echo "$v1"
```

*Note.* Avoid using backticks, use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: The backticks in the OP's `v1=\`cat ...\`` got lost due to misquoting, which is fixed now.